# Constructing variadic template arguments from initializer lists, without specifying constructor

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates

I have a struct like this, which represents the ability to check if some named value matches what is expected:

```
template <typename TValue>
struct pair
{
  std::string key;
  TValue value;

  template <typename T>
  struct no_overload_error : std::false_type {};

  // there is some storage where values named by `key` are expected
  bool check() const
  {
    static_assert(no_overload_error<TValue>::value, "Cannot check this data type.");
  }
};
```

The `check()` method will be implemented for specific data types. The code I am writing should allow me to do this:

```
// some unit test, if any of these is not what is expected, it will fail the test
check_values({"name of bool val", true}, {"some int", 24}, {"a double", 1.5});
```

To do that, I wrote this:

```
template <typename TFirst, typename ... Values>
void check_values(pair<TFirst> first, pair<Values> ... pairs)
{
  first.check();
  if constexpr (sizeof...(pairs) > 0)
  {
    check_values(pairs...);
  }
}
```

And it almost works, but I have to use it like this:

```
check_values(pair{ "bool", true }, pair{ "int", 22 });
```

It's still better than the original approach of `check_if_is_int("dddd", 22)` and so on.

But is it possible to write it so that the compiler knows `{std::string, TVal}` means I want it to create one pair?

Comment: Why not giving a complete minimal example of what you've got so far?

Comment: What error do you get if you omit the pair? Do you have a link to a live example?

Comment: I can only reproduce after adding a deduction guide for `pair`: https://godbolt.org/z/3oEG476T6. I think you are out of luck. The brace-enclosed initializer list `{...}` can only be automatically deduced to `std::initializer_list` or arrays AFAIK. The compiler does not know that you mean `pair<int>` by `{"int", 22}`. It could just as well be `std::pair<std::string, int>`.

Comment: Yeah, i am thinking the same as @joergbrech. My attempt fails because of the brace closed initialiser list: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c3ea7ccb6c01626c

Comment: You can do it if you just pass the names and values all as a single list: https://godbolt.org/z/Kzo9Ea1Yn

Comment: @AlanBirtles I considered single list. I didn't know how to do it, and also kinda liked the separated pairs. But your solution is still very cool! Thanks!

Comment: Aside: `no_overload_error` probably shouldn't be a member of `pair`, because you have to specialise `pair` to change it.

Comment: @Caleth Could you please elaborate a little? I am not sure what you mean. It is only there to prevent the method from asserting unless it is the only overload left.

Comment: @TomášZato oh, I was slightly wrong, `template <> template <> struct pair<int>::no_overload_error<int> : std::true_type {};` allows `int` to be checked

Answer (score 0):

A partial solution to your problem is to pass all the values as a single list of arguments:

```
template <typename TFirst, typename ... More>
void check_values(std::string&& key, TFirst&& value, More... more)
{
  pair<TFirst> first{std::move(key), std::forward<TFirst>(value)};
  first.check();
  if constexpr (sizeof...(more) > 0)
  {
    check_values(more...);
  }
}

int main()
{
    check_values("name of bool val", true, "some int", 24, "a double", 1.5);
}
```

You'll get some obscure compile errors though if the arguments are incorrect.